# Equation numbering and combined blocks (aligned)

Tags: align, amsmath

I have 2 sets à 2 equations which I want to print side by side with a centered arrow in between, and equation numbers (1a), (1b) on the right. But I cannot get the numbering right. The closest I was able to get is with

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
    \begin{aligned}
        a &= b \\ c &=d
    \end{aligned}
    && \implies &&
    \begin{aligned}
        x &=y \\ z &= w
    \end{aligned}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Which obviously only prints one equation number....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `empheq` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\begin{document}
\begin{subequations}
\begin{empheq}[left={\begin{aligned}
        a &= b \\ c &=d
    \end{aligned}}\quad\implies\quad]{align}
    x &=y \\ z &= w
\end{empheq}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Damn! I was just going to post it :) +1

Comment: This feels a little cheesy (since it doesn't generalize well to more complicated cases), but I guess I'm gonna go with it anyway.